# How to connect android T.V emulator to internet?

Tags: android, android-tv

I am using android T.V emulator but the internet is not working. I use the api 23. is there other work around in order to connect the android T.V emulator to internet.

Note: my laptop is connected via wifi.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's very strange. You're talking about the AndroidTV emulator on your PC. Right? If your PC has internet access, your emulator should have internet access. Did you ask for the internet permission in the manifest of your app? Does your app work on the standard emulator for a phone/tablet?

Comment: Yes I have that configuration in my manifest

Comment: Does your PC have a firewall turned on?

Comment: Yes , I turned off the firewall.still I cannot have internet access...I also turn on the wifi settings in the emulator but keeps getting off when I turn back to the home.

Comment: Try connecting your laptop to ethernet. Real Android TVs can work with ethernet, unlike Android phones.

Comment: I also have the same problem. I launched the default Nexus 5 avd then installed and opened chrome and its working. Then i created a new avd using api 23 but this time its an android TV. I also installed opened chrome but it cant connect the internet. Tried turning on the emulator's wifi but it always go back to "off"

Answer (score 3):

This problem was solved. Please check updates. Google released a new update for API23_x86 and API23_arm emulators.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [thread](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/issues/50) to clear things up. For now the only solution is to use an older Android version(API 22 and below) to make the emulator for Android TV connect to the internet.